# Expectation of a non-linear matrix combination

Tags: probability, matrices, expected-value

We want to find the following expectation

$\mathbb{E[\mathrm{tr}\big(\frac{\mathrm{\mathbf A^\mathrm{H} \mathbf x \mathbf y^\mathrm{H}}}{\mathbf y^\mathrm{H}\mathbf A^\mathrm{H}\mathbf A\mathbf y}\big)] }$

where $\mathbf x\in \mbox{$\mathbb{C}$}^{M\times 1}$, and $\mathbf y\in \mbox{$\mathbb{C}$}^{MN \times 1}$, and for example $\mathbf A^\mathrm{H}$ means hermitian of matrix $\mathbf A$. Also, assume that the matrices $\mathbb{E[\mathbf x \mathbf y^\mathrm{H}]} $ and  $\mathbb{E[\mathbf y \mathbf y^\mathrm{H}]}$ are given. $\mathbf A$ is also given. Is there any exact or approximation approach to find above expectation? thanks a lot.

Comment: Where's the stochastic process?

Comment: which quantities are random? which deterministic?

Comment: $\mathbf x$ and $ \mathbf y$ are random vectors. $\mathbf A$ is deterministic.

Comment: You can write the expression a bit more simply as
$$
\mathbb E \left(\frac{y^HA^Hx}{y^HA^HAy} \right)
$$

Comment: Remember, we have a trace inside the expectation. the output of the expectation is scalar.

Comment: if you know how to solve it with $A$ diagonal, then you can solve it for any $A$ thanks to the SVD

Comment: Random vectors aren't stochastic processes unless they are indexed across a set (like time)

Comment: @Amin Yes, the rewritten version I suggested is also a scalar

Comment: Yes, you true actually this problem is just for finding expectation. Indeed it's static in time. I just wanted to make up the problem in more communities.

Comment: I think it is not possible. In fact, take everything scalar and $A=1$. CAn you find $E[x/y]$ knowing only $E[y^2]$ and $E[xy]$? I think not...

Comment: It is possible, however, to separately find the expectation $\mathbb E(\operatorname{tr}(A^Hxy^H))$ of the numerator and $\mathbb E(\operatorname{tr}(A^HAyy^H) )$ of the denominator.

Comment: Another thing maybe helps here is $\mathrm M$ as the size of the vector is large.

Comment: @Ben, I think we can not divide expectation operator over the numerator and denominator separately.

Comment: give up, it's impossible to find the exact value. At most you can look for bounds

Comment: @Amin Yes, that’s why the word “however” is in there